# Undefined Index in array from xml

Tags: php, soap

I am getting "Undefined Index FruitOrder" in an if statement for an array which is created from XML/Soap Response

Code:

```
$response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $resp);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
    $body = $xml->xpath('//soapBody ')[0];
    $array = json_decode(json_encode($body), TRUE);

    if($array['FruitOrder']['FruitCode'] == 'FruitSuccess' || $array['FruitOrder']['FruitCode'] == 'FruitSuccessWarnings')
    {
```

Comment: To avoid `Undefined Index` error you should check if the items exists in array with `isset`. If the error is not expected, you should also share the data in $resp.

Comment: Could you give an example for my case?

Comment: Example added as answer

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the `Undefined Index` error you should check if the item `['FruitOrder']['FruitCode']` exists in the array with `isset`.

```php
    if(isset($array['FruitOrder']['FruitCode']) 
    && ($array['FruitOrder']['FruitCode'] === 'FruitSuccess'
    || $array['FruitOrder']['FruitCode'] === 'FruitSuccessWarnings'))
    {
        echo 'process the data';
    }
```